# R Stan: Rejecting initial value error only with real data, not with simulated data

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, stan, rstan

I am trying to fit a non-linear function to a dataset using Stan and R. I tested my model with a simulated dataset. It works nicely. However, as soon as I use real data that is formatted exactly the same as the simulated data, I get the error:

> Rejecting initial value. Gradient evaluated at the initial value is not finite.

How can this be?

This is my stan file:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  real<lower=0, upper=1> p1[N];
  real<lower=0, upper=1> p2[N];
  real W1[N];
  real W2[N];
  real U[N];
}


parameters {
  real<lower=0, upper=1> r;
  real<lower=0> s;
  real<lower=0> tau;
}

transformed parameters {
  real pred[N];
  
  for (i in 1:N) {
    pred[i] = exp(-s*(-log(p1[i]))^r) * W1[i] + exp(-s*(-log(p2[i]))^r) * W2[i];
  }
}

model {
  // priors
  r ~ gamma(1, 1);
  s ~ gamma(1, 1);
  tau ~ gamma(1, 1);
  
  // model
  U ~ normal(pred, tau);
}
```

This is the relevant R code:

```
df = data.frame(p1 = as.vector(df$p1),
            p2 = as.vector(df$p2),
                W1 = rep(-5, nrow(df)),
                W2 = rep(-1, nrow(df)),
                U = as.vector(df$U))

#----RStan----
stan.data = c(as.list(df), N = nrow(df))

fit = stan("kortenkamp.stan",
           data=stan.data)
```

These are summaries of the simulated and the real dataset:

Simulated:

```
id            case           p1                p2               W1           W2           r                 s              error       
 Min.   : 1.0   Min.   :1.0   Min.   :0.00329   Min.   :0.6037   Min.   :-1   Min.   :-5   Min.   :0.08291   Min.   :0.4841   Min.   :0.2602  
 1st Qu.:13.0   1st Qu.:1.0   1st Qu.:0.06381   1st Qu.:0.6536   1st Qu.:-1   1st Qu.:-5   1st Qu.:0.08961   1st Qu.:0.6450   1st Qu.:0.4497  
 Median :25.5   Median :1.5   Median :0.10819   Median :0.7011   Median :-1   Median :-5   Median :0.09930   Median :0.7253   Median :0.5179  
 Mean   :25.5   Mean   :1.5   Mean   :0.10703   Mean   :0.6980   Mean   :-1   Mean   :-5   Mean   :0.10021   Mean   :0.7198   Mean   :0.5094  
 3rd Qu.:38.0   3rd Qu.:2.0   3rd Qu.:0.15757   3rd Qu.:0.7460   3rd Qu.:-1   3rd Qu.:-5   3rd Qu.:0.10913   3rd Qu.:0.7849   3rd Qu.:0.5626  
 Max.   :50.0   Max.   :2.0   Max.   :0.19998   Max.   :0.7998   Max.   :-1   Max.   :-5   Max.   :0.12677   Max.   :0.9536   Max.   :0.8519  
         U         
 Min.   :-4.757  
 1st Qu.:-3.540  
 Median :-3.126  
 Mean   :-3.070  
 3rd Qu.:-2.617  
 Max.   :-1.223
```

Real:

```
       p1               p2               W1           W2           U        
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :-5   Min.   :-1   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:0.2150   1st Qu.:0.7300   1st Qu.:-5   1st Qu.:-1   1st Qu.:3.000  
 Median :0.4000   Median :0.8550   Median :-5   Median :-1   Median :4.000  
 Mean   :0.4222   Mean   :0.8133   Mean   :-5   Mean   :-1   Mean   :4.178  
 3rd Qu.:0.6000   3rd Qu.:0.9500   3rd Qu.:-5   3rd Qu.:-1   3rd Qu.:6.000  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :-5   Max.   :-1   Max.   :9.000
```

The data is simulated like this:

```
pr = function(p, r, s){
  return(exp(-s*(-log(p))^r))
}

n = 100

df_sim = data.frame(id = rep(1:50, 2),
                case = c(rep(1, 50), rep(2, 50)),
                p1 = sample(seq(0, 0.2, 0.00001), n),
                p2 = sample(seq(0.6, 0.8, 0.00001), n),
                W1 = -1, 
                W2 = -5,
                r = rep(rnorm(n/2, 0.1, 0.01), 2),
                s = rep(rnorm(n/2, 0.7, 0.1), 2),
                error = rnorm(n, 0.5, 0.1))

df_sim$U1 = df_sim$p1 * df_sim$W1
df_sim$U2 = df_sim$p2 * df_sim$W2

df_sim$Y = pr(df_sim$p1, df_sim$r, df_sim$s) * df_sim$W1 + pr(df_sim$p2, df_sim$r, df_sim$s) * df_sim$W2 + rnorm(n, 0, df_sim$error)

stan.data = list(
  N = nrow(df_sim),
  p1 = df_sim$p1,
  p2 = df_sim$p2,
  W1 = df_sim$W1,
  W2 = df_sim$W2,
  U = df_sim$Y)
```

A snippet of the real data:

```
p1   p2   W1  W2  U
0.4  0.9  -5  -1  2
0.2  0.95 -5  -1  2
0.4  0.8  -5  -1  2
0.9  0.41 -5  -1  3
0.6  0.84 -5  -1  7
0.2  0.75 -5  -1  6
0.5  1    -5  -1  4
```

I am completely new to Bayesian approaches, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would need the contents of `df` to actually help.  Can you post that?

Comment: I added the data simulation and some real data.

Comment: Can you please examine your minimal working example again?  it doesn't seem to run

Comment: My apologies, was missing a function definition.

Comment: I just noticed that to-be-predicted values in simulated data are negative, however in real data they are positive. Multiplying the column in real data with -1 (which would be theoretically meaningful) did not solve my issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this.  With cmdstanr...

```
library(cmdstanr)
code<-'data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  real<lower=0, upper=1> p1[N];
  real<lower=0, upper=1> p2[N];
  real W1[N];
  real W2[N];
  real U[N];
}


parameters {
  real<lower=0, upper=1> r;
  real<lower=0> s;
  real<lower=0> tau;
}

transformed parameters {
  real pred[N];
  
  for (i in 1:N) {
    pred[i] = exp(-s*(-log(p1[i]))^r) * W1[i] + exp(-s*(-log(p2[i]))^r) * W2[i];
  }
}

model {
  // priors
  r ~ gamma(1, 1);
  s ~ gamma(1, 1);
  tau ~ gamma(1, 1);
  
  // model
  U ~ normal(pred, tau);
}'


model = cmdstan_model(write_stan_file(code))


stan_data = list(
  p1 = c(4,2,4,9,6,2,5)/10,
  p2 = c(9, 9.5, 8, 4.1, 8.4, 7.5, 10)/10,
  W1 = -5*rep(1, 7),
  W2 = -1*rep(1, 7),
  U = c(2,2,2,3,7,6,4),
  N = 7
)

fit = model$sample(stan_data)
```

I do get a warning about metrpopolis proposals being rejected, but the warning appears once and not again making me think Stan is just being cautious (which is fine).

Here is the summary

````
fit
 variable   mean median   sd  mad     q5    q95 rhat ess_bulk ess_tail
  lp__    -22.73 -22.38 1.33 1.09 -25.37 -21.27 1.00     1695     1975
  r         0.29   0.23 0.23 0.22   0.02   0.76 1.00     3472     2268
  s         3.15   2.94 1.40 1.26   1.25   5.70 1.00     2760     1849
  tau       4.35   4.21 0.99 0.94   3.02   6.17 1.00     2784     2458
  pred[1]  -0.70  -0.52 0.64 0.47  -2.02  -0.06 1.00     2677     1921
  pred[2]  -0.64  -0.51 0.55 0.42  -1.74  -0.07 1.00     2543     1870
  pred[3]  -0.63  -0.44 0.63 0.43  -1.94  -0.05 1.00     2734     1837
  pred[4]  -1.34  -1.04 1.07 0.96  -3.52  -0.12 1.00     2834     1927
  pred[5]  -0.82  -0.60 0.76 0.57  -2.37  -0.07 1.00     2793     1883
  pred[6]  -0.50  -0.32 0.54 0.33  -1.61  -0.03 1.00     2744     1881

 # showing 10 of 11 rows (change via 'max_rows' argument)
```
````

Comment: Thanks very much for your work on this. This is really interesting. I will also give it a try using cmdstanr. And I will check row by row of the real data, if there is anything strange happening. What should I be looking out for with this kind of error? What are possible sources?